# Matlab: Numerical imprecision for the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a `520 x 520` `mat` matrix with `2` on the diagonal and `1` off-diagonal. If I do `inv(mat)*mat`, I do not get an identity matrix. I get `1` on the diagonal but -0.000000001, -0.000000002, or 0.000000004. Why is that?

Comment: Take a look at the answer in the duplicate I have linked.  You will see why `inv(mat)*mat` is not desired, and that you should really be using `mat \ mat` instead (which should give you identity).

Comment: Oh I see! thanks for answer and sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: Not a problem at all :)  This is a common question that people ask.  I marked it as a duplicate so that people who come here will know the answer immediately.  I had to do a bit of digging to find it.  No need to apologize!  Good luck!